# Tex capacity exceeded sorry input stacksize=5000

Tags: errors, cleveref

I am getting this error while trying to build my tex file.
As soon as I include the `cleveref` package, I get this error and it shows
`cleveref.sty` with the cursor at the bolded part of the file.

```
\def\make@df@tag@@@#1{%
    \gdef\df@tag{\tagform@{#1}%
      \toks@\@xp{\p@equation{#1}}%
      \edef\@currentlabel{\the\toks@}%
      \edef\cref@currentlabel{[equation][2147483647][]\the\toks@}}}
**}{}%  end of \@ifpackageloaded{amsmath}**
\@ifpackageloaded{IEEEtrantools}{%
  \PackageInfo{cleveref}{`IEEEtrantools' support loaded}
  \let\cref@orig@@IEEEeqnarray\@@IEEEeqnarray
  \def\@@IEEEeqnarray[#1]#2{%
    \refstepcounter{equation}%
```

What could be the reason for this error?

from the comments:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{example.eps}
gsave newpath 20 20 moveto 20 220 lineto 220 220 lineto 220 20 lineto
closepath 2 setlinewidth gsave .4 setgray fill grestore stroke grestore
\end{filecontents*}
\RequirePackage{fix-cm} 
\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3} 
\smartqed \let\proof\relax \let\endproof\relax \usepackage{cleveref} 
\begin{document} 
\title{Title} \author{First Author} \date{Received: date / Accepted: date} 
\maketitle 
\begin{abstract} \end{abstract} 
\maketitle 
\section{Introduction} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) if you indent a sample code block by 4 spaces, or click on the `{}` icon, it will be highlighted.  inline code can be highlighted by surrounding it with backticks. (i've edited those code highlighters into your question.)  please also  include a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: \begin{filecontents*}{example.eps}
gsave
newpath
  20 20 moveto
  20 220 lineto
  220 220 lineto
  220 20 lineto
closepath
2 setlinewidth
gsave
  .4 setgray fill
grestore
stroke
grestore
\end{filecontents*}
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}

\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3} 
\smartqed  
\let\proof\relax 
\let\endproof\relax
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
\title{Title}

\author{First Author}


\date{Received: date / Accepted: date}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
\end{abstract}
\maketitle


\section{Introduction}

\end{document}

Comment: I have added the MWE, but I dot not know how to properly indent it while submitting. Could you please help me in this regard.

Comment: @VaibhavSundriyal code in comments looks horrible:-) You can edit it into the question (but I just did it in this case)

Comment: A [duplicate of this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/327414) has been asked. The [fix proposed over there](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/327686) is simpler and less intrusive than the solutions for this question.

Answer (score 31):

svjour3 isn't in texlive but I got a copy from the springer site. It appears to have a bug and your document goes into an infinite loop `\cl@chapter` is defined to expand to itself. This fixes (or at least avoids) that immediate problem.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{example.eps}
gsave newpath 20 20 moveto 20 220 lineto 220 220 lineto 220 20 lineto closepath 2 setlinewidth gsave .4 setgray fill grestore stroke grestore \end{filecontents*}
\RequirePackage{fix-cm} 
\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3} 
\smartqed \let\proof\relax \let\endproof\relax

\makeatletter
%\def\cl@chapter{\cl@chapter \@elt {theorem}}%bug in class
\def\cl@chapter{\@elt {theorem}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{cleveref} 

\begin{document}

\title{Title} \author{First Author} \date{Received: date / Accepted: date} 
\maketitle 
\begin{abstract} \end{abstract} 


\section{Introduction} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: In order to make it clearer, the three lines are required including `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`. A bit late, but this should be marked as the accepted answer.

Comment: if you need to use theorem (and not chapter) then use instead \def\cl@chapter{\@elt {chapter}}

Comment: @user3680510 that looks wrong, why set chapter to 0 every time you increment chapter?

Comment: i have a document, where i do not use chapter, but i use \begin{theorem} \end{theorem} with your approach i  get a You can't use `\relax' after \the. \begin{theorem} error. When i do the hack i mention it works, but i dont know what is going on.

Comment: @user3680510 you are free to post a question, but leaving comments on old answers doesn't really work given the site mechanisms.

Answer (score 10):

First, your truely minimal MWE (except for whitespace) would be this:

```
\documentclass{svjour3}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}
    \section{}
\end{document}
```

Now adding to David Carlisle's answer (but the comment field is too short):

I think the problem is the `\@addtoreset{theorem}{chapter}` in `svjour3.cls`. At least, I can reproduce the problem in this MWE independent of `svjour3`:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{theorem}{chapter}
\makeatother
\usepackage{cleveref} 
\begin{document} 
    \section{}
\end{document}
```

Of course, `article` (same as `svjour3`) does not have a `\chapter`:

```
\documentclass{svjour3}
\begin{document}
    \chapter{}
\end{document}
```

Now, `\@addtoreset` looks like this in `latex.ltx`:

```
\def\@addtoreset#1#2{\expandafter\@cons\csname cl@#2\endcsname {{#1}}}
\def\@cons#1#2{\begingroup\let\@elt\relax\xdef#1{#1\@elt #2}\endgroup}
```

What it does is nicely explained here:
https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb18-4/tb57work.pdf
It seems to fail, though, when trying to use it on a sectioning element that is not defined; hence, expansion of `\cl@chapter` fails when redefining `\cl@chapter` to add `\@elt {theorem}` to the list.

So one solution would be to patch `\@addtoreset`/`\@cons` to check for the existence of `\cl@<unit>` when redefining `\cl@<unit>`. This should not be too hard, for example:

```
\makeatletter
%\def\@cons#1#2{\begingroup\let\@elt\relax\xdef#1{#1\@elt #2}\endgroup}
\def\@cons#1#2{\begingroup\let\@elt\relax\xdef#1{\ifx#1\relax\else#1\fi\@elt #2}\endgroup}
\makeatother
\documentclass{svjour3}
\usepackage{cleveref} 
\begin{document} 
    \section{}
\end{document}
```

It should still made sure by someone knowing latex better than me whether `\@cons` still does what it shall do in all circumstances, and whether this patch would make sense in `latex.ltx`. Follow http://www.latex-project.org/cgi-bin/ltxbugs2html?pr=latex/4427 on that if interested.

Until (or if not) this is done, I propose the following workaround:

```
\makeatletter
\def\cl@chapter{}
\makeatother
\documentclass{svjour3}
\usepackage{cleveref} 
\begin{document} 
    \section{}
\end{document}
```

You can easily check by commenting the second line that this reproduces (and fixes, by uncommenting) the error seen.

Comment: Nice explanation!

Comment: It would be wrong to change `\@cons` I think, it would perhaps be possible to make `\@addtoreset` check that `cl@#2` is defined. Of course the real fix is to report the bug to Springer and hopefully get the class fixed.