# svjour3 and certain packages conflict?

Tags: packages, pdf, sv-classes

How can I found out which packages cause problems with the class `svjour3`?

After many compilations I found out that the problem lies in of the packages I use. The code is below and does not produce a pdf.

EDIT 1: The file svjour3.cls was modified on 1/10/2008. I use MiKTeX 2.9.

EDIT 2: The error is

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\cl@chapter ->\cl@chapter 
                          \@elt {theorem}
l.2486 }{}
          %  end of \@ifpackageloaded{amsmath}
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on probleem.log.
```

PDFLaTeX Compilation Report:

```
(Pages: 0) Errors: 2   Warnings: 2   Bad Boxes: 0



\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{undertilde}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage[sort&compress,round,comma,authoryear]{natbib}%bibtex
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[titletoc,title]{appendix}% for appendix met A
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{dcolumn}


\begin{document}
Hello
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, which TeX distribution do you use, is it up to date, which version number has class `svjour` and **important** which error message did you get?  Please add theese infos to your question!

Comment: The file svjour3.cls was modified on 1/10/2008.

Comment: Please add a link to that version you use. As far as I know is the last version from springer defined with: `\ProvidesClass{svjour3}[2007/05/08 v3.2` ...

Comment: See (ctrl + f 'latex macro package') http://www.springer.com/?SGWID=0-102-6-791955-0

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 12):

The problem appears when `cleveref` is being loaded and it shows only when `amsmath` is loaded, because in this case `cleveref` does some checks and redefinitions.

The issue is an error in `svjour` which does

```
\if@envcntsect
   \def\@thmcountersep{.}
   \spnewtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]{\bfseries}{\itshape}
\else
   \spnewtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}{\bfseries}{\itshape}
   \if@envcntreset
      \@addtoreset{theorem}{section}
   \else
      \@addtoreset{theorem}{chapter}
   \fi
\fi
```

and the `\@addtoreset{theorem}{chapter}` line makes no sense whatsoever, as the class doesn't support chapters.

You can fix this by defining a dummy `chapter` counter.

```
\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{undertilde} % not in TeX Live
%\usepackage{amsthm} % incompatible with svjour3
%\usepackage{epsfig} % obsolete
%\usepackage{graphics} % loaded by graphicx
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{caption} % incompatible with svjour3
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfigure} % deprecated!!!
\usepackage[sort&compress,round,comma,authoryear]{natbib}%bibtex
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[titletoc,title]{appendix}% for appendix met A
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcounter{chapter} % to fix the bug in svjour3
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

Hello

\end{document}
```

I have commented out some packages: `undertilde` is not on my system, probably you're better served with the `accents` package (remember to load it after `amsmath`); the others I commented are either obsolete or incompatible with `svjour3` (besides some raising errors).

Instead of `subfigure` you can use

```
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
```

which has `\subfloat` instead of `\subfigure` and `\subtable` (an easy change).